# JPA + Spring: Mapping a foreign key column to a ID based on the value received before persisting the entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

Please excuse me if it is a dumb question, but I am very much new to JPA and Spring.
I am wondering if someone can help with the below problem as I did a lot of search on StackOverflow and google but couldn't find any example for my use case. It could be that I am missing the keyword as I don't know what this sort of mapping is called in JPA.

So basically, I am trying to develop a REST API to retrieve and insert a record from/in a database and for which I have two tables namely `CLIENT_MASTER` and `TITLE`.

The schema for `CLIENT_MASTER` looks as below,

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT_MASTER (
   ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1000),
   TITLE_ID INT,
   FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(255),
   MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR(255),
   LAST_NAME VARCHAR(255),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Similarly, the scheme for the `TITLE` table is,

```
CREATE TABLE TITLE (
   ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
   TITLE VARCHAR(10),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

The `CLIENT_MASTER` table has the below foreign key constraint,

```
ALTER TABLE CLIENT_MASTER ADD CONSTRAINT TITLE_ID FOREIGN KEY (TITLE_ID) REFERENCES TITLE;
```

The entity for both the tables is defined as below,

```
import java.io.Serializable;
...
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT_MASTER")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ClientMaster implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TITLE_ID")
    private Title title;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "MIDDLE_NAME")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
}

import java.io.Serializable;
....
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TITLE")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Title implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;
}
```

And in my rest controller, I have below to insert the new client

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody ClientMaster cm) {
    cmrepository.create(cm);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    ControllerLinkBuilder linkBuilder = linkTo(methodOn(CompanyController.class).get(cm.getId()));
    headers.setLocation(linkBuilder.toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

where `cmrepository` is the instance of,

```
@Repository
public class CMRepository {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public void create(ClientMaster cm) {
    entityManager.persist(cm);

 }
}
```

I'm sending the below json in the post request and what I want is to map the title value to its respective id from the `TITLE` table and insert the record with correct title id.

```
{
    "title": {
        "title": "Mr"
    },
    "firstName": "XXX",
    "middleName": "YYY",
    "lastName": "ZZZ",
}
```

With the above, the current behaviour is that for each record insert in `CLIENT_TABLE`, there's a new record getting created in the `TITLE` table which is not I want.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction as for how this can be achieved?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Instead of 
      
       CascadeType.ALL

Try setting it only to MERGE

Comment: @vc73 Changing the `CascadeType` to `MERGE` didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that the persistence provider will auto-assume the id by field value itself.

You have to:

1. Fetch the `Title` entry first by the `title`.
2. Set the `title` on `ClientMaster` if it was fetched.. do nothing otherwise and allow the cascade to persist that value.
3. Use `merge` instead of `persist` on the `ClientMaster` object:

   `cmrepository.merge(cm);`

Comment: Why the `merge` a `persist` would work fine even with existing references objects.

Comment: If you fetch the Title entity.. it will be in detached state before persist. And if you try to persist a detached entity (through cascade here) you will get an exception

Comment: Unless Transactional is set on the controller level. but that we do not know

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I have posted my answer below. Sorry, I can't mark this answer useful because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys

I followed Maciej's suggestion and now my controller looks as below

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody ClientMaster company) {
    //fetch and set title. 
    company.setTitle(titleService.get(company.getTitle().getTitle()));
    companyService.create(company);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    ControllerLinkBuilder linkBuilder = linkTo(methodOn(CompanyController.class).get(company.getId()));
    headers.setLocation(linkBuilder.toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its a good idea to not have it insert though , since you have defined a forgien key relation its always better for the title table to have all the IDs stored.

Comment: No, there are only predefined set of Titles which are initialized after table creation. If the title in request doesn't matches from any of the existing titles then the end user won't be able to insert any record in client_master table. That's basically a requirement.